# Intermediate fields of Gal($x^5-2$, $\mathbb{Q}$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I'm having trouble findind the fixed field of each subgroup of the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q(\alpha, \omega)}$, where $\alpha = 2^{\frac{1}{5}}$ and $\omega$ is a 5-th primitive root of unity. I list here the 20 automorphisms of the Galois group, $G$:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&I & \sigma & \sigma^2 & \sigma^3 & \sigma^4 & \tau & \tau^2 & \tau^3 & \sigma\circ\tau &\sigma\circ\tau^2\\ \hline
\alpha& \alpha & \alpha\omega &\alpha\omega^2&\alpha\omega^3&\alpha\omega^4&\alpha&\alpha&\alpha&\alpha\omega&\alpha\omega  \\ \hline
\omega& \omega  &\omega &\omega&\omega&\omega&\omega^2&\omega^4&\omega^3&\omega^2&\omega^4\\ \hline
\end{array}

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 &\sigma\circ\tau^3 &\sigma^2\circ\tau &\sigma^2\circ\tau^2 &\sigma^2\circ\tau^3 &\sigma^3\circ\tau &\sigma^3\circ\tau^2 &\sigma^3\circ\tau^3 &\sigma^4\circ\tau &\sigma^4\circ\tau^2 &\sigma^4\tau^3 \\ \hline
\alpha& \alpha\omega &\alpha\omega^2 &\alpha\omega^2 &\alpha\omega^2 &\alpha\omega^3 &\alpha\omega^3 &\alpha\omega^3 &\alpha\omega^4 &\alpha\omega^4 &\alpha\omega^4\\ \hline
\omega &\omega^3 &\omega^2& \omega^4& \omega^3& \omega^2&\omega^4&\omega^3&\omega^2&\omega^4 &\omega^3\\ \hline
\end{array}

The subgroups are:

> {I},
>
> {I, $\sigma \circ \tau^2$}, {I,$\sigma^2 \circ \tau^2$ }, {I,$\sigma^3 \circ \tau^2$ }, {I,$\sigma^4 \circ \tau^2$ }, {I,$\tau^2$ }
>
> {I, $\tau, \tau^2, \tau^3$}
>
> {I, $\sigma, \sigma^2, \sigma^3, \sigma^4$}
>
> {I,$\sigma, \sigma^2, \sigma^3, \sigma^4, \tau^2, \sigma \circ \tau^2, \sigma^2 \circ \tau^2, \sigma^3 \circ \tau^2, \sigma^4 \circ \tau^2 $}
>
> $G$

{I} fixes $\mathbb{Q(\alpha, \omega)}$;

G fixes $\mathbb{Q}$;

{I, $\tau, \tau^2, \tau^3$} fixes $\mathbb{Q(\alpha)}$;

{I, $\sigma, \sigma^2, \sigma^3, \sigma^4$} fixes $\mathbb{Q(\omega)}$

However, I can't see what are the others fixed fields...

I believe {I,$\sigma, \sigma^2, \sigma^3, \sigma^4, \tau^2, \sigma \circ \tau^2, \sigma^2 \circ \tau^2, \sigma^3 \circ \tau^2, \sigma^4 \circ \tau^2 $} fixes $\mathbb{Q(\omega + \omega^4)}$, but then I'd have to show that $[\mathbb{Q(\omega + \omega^4)}:\mathbb{Q}]=2$, but I don't know what is the minimal polynomial of $\omega + \omega^4$.

Same for the subgroups of order 2. I'd have to find extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ of order 10 that are fixed by the automorphisms in the subgroup. For example, I know that {I, $\sigma\circ\tau^2$} fixes $\mathbb{Q(\alpha\omega^3)}, \mathbb{Q(\alpha + \alpha\omega)}, \mathbb{Q(\alpha\omega^4+\alpha\omega^2)}, \mathbb{Q(\omega+\omega^4)}, \mathbb{Q(\omega^2+\omega^3)}$, so the fixed field must contain all of this subfields and have degree 10 over $\mathbb{Q}$, but how to find it?

Can someone give a help? Thanks!

Comment: Here $\omega+\omega^4=2\cos(2\pi/5)=(-1+\sqrt5)/2$, so $\Bbb{Q}(\omega+\omega^4)=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt5)$. This suggests that the real subfield is $\Bbb{Q}(\root5\of2,\sqrt5)$. This has certain "obvious" conjugate fields. A general fact worth remembering is that for all odd primes $p$, the field $\Bbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/p})$ has a unique quadratic subfield that is $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{(-1)^{(p-1)/2}p})$. BTW, well done listing the automorphisms and subgroups! Looks like you're getting good answers. I won't be needed here :-) +1 to all!

Comment: Noticed one thing. Your list is missing a few subgroups. Namely the conjugates of $\langle \tau\rangle$. For example $\sigma\circ \tau$ also has order four. The fixed fields of these subgroups are of the form $\Bbb{Q}(\alpha\omega^i)$ for some $i$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks!!! Is there a easy way to find all the subgroups? When I found the subgroups I listed I was afraid I was forgeting someone, which I was, indeed :(

Comment: Oddly enough, nobody seems to have addressed the fact that it may be important to know first *what* group are we dealing with (and if somebody did and I missed it I apologize). Even granting that it is "clear" the group isn't abelian, there are still three non abelian non-isomorphic groups of order $\;20\;$, all of them realizable as direct products $\; C_5\rtimes H\;$ , with $\;H=C_4\;\;or\;\; C_2\times C_2\;$ .Knowing this seems to be important to know what subgroups can we expect to be there.

Comment: @Timbuc What is the third possibility? And you're right haha knowing what group is this will make tha task of finding the subgroups a lot easier haha

Comment: @CarolLafetá, what "third possibility"? I don't understand.

Comment: There are two semi-direct products $C_5\rtimes C_4$. That might be the third possibility you mean?

Comment: Oh, that. Yes, @HSN , perhaps that's what she meant. Thanks.

Comment: @Timbuc you said there are three non abelin non-isomorphic groups of order 20, all of them realizable as direct products $C_5 X H$, with $H=C_4$ or $C_2 X C_2$. There are only two groups here hehe

Comment: What? What did I mean? hahahaha I'm lost

Comment: I didn't write "direct" products but **semidirect** products, @Carol. This is a big difference, of course.

Comment: I didn't know that symbol between $C_5$ and $H$ meant semidirect product! Thanks!

Comment: This group is *the holomorph of* $C_5$, $G\cong C_5\rtimes Aut(C_5)$. The index two subgroup that Carol found is $D_5$. With an appropriate labeling of the five vertices (or the five roots) $D_5$ acts via permutations that map the edges of the pentagon to each other. The permutations in $G\setminus D_5$ map the edges of the pentagon to those of a pentagram (and vice versa).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, concerning your question about $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega+\omega^4):\mathbb{Q}]$. There is a nice fact that is often useful when dealing with roots of unity. Namely, if $\omega_n$ is an $n$th root of unity ($n$ at least 3) and if $\theta_n=\omega_n+\omega_n^{-1}$, we have $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega_n):\mathbb{Q}] = 2\cdot[\mathbb{Q}(\theta_n):\mathbb{Q}]$. Why is this? Well, $\theta_n\in\mathbb{R}$, whereas $\omega_n\in\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$, so $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega_n):\mathbb{Q}(\theta_n)]\geq 2$.

Moreover, $\theta_n\omega_n=\omega_n^2+1$, so $\omega_n$ is the zero of $x^2-\theta_nx+1\in\mathbb{Q}(\theta_n)[x]$. This tells us that $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega_n):\mathbb{Q}(\theta_n)]\leq 2$. Combining this with the previous result, it has to equal $2$. In your particular case, this indeed gives you that $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega+\omega^4):\mathbb{Q}]=2$. To find an actual minimal polynomial of $\omega+\omega^4$, one can square this expression, and hope to find something containing $1+\omega+\omega^2+\omega^3+\omega^4=1$ there. Unless I'm much mistaken, one could obtain $x^2+x-1$ this way.

Now, for the subfields, you already gave four rather important ones and to find the rest is some sort of puzzling exercise. First of all, $\{1,\tau^2\}<\{1,\tau,\tau^2,\tau^3\}$, so the field fixed by this subgroup of order two has to be a field inbetween $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega)$ and there's a perfectly suitable candidate: $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega+\omega^4)$. Moreover, you already managed to find that $\{1,\sigma,\sigma^2,\sigma^3,\sigma^4,\tau^2,\sigma\circ \tau^2,\sigma^2\circ \tau^2,\sigma^3\circ \tau^2,\sigma^4\circ \tau^2\}$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}(\omega+\omega^4)$ and are hopefully convinced of this by now.

The question that remains is to find four subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\omega)$, having $\mathbb{Q}(\omega+\omega^4)$ as a subfield and being of degree $5$ over this subfield. It looks an aweful lot like these should be $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\omega,\omega+\omega^4)$, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\omega^2,\omega+\omega^4)$, $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\omega^3,\omega+\omega^4)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\omega^4,\omega+\omega^4)$. Can you fill in the gaps?

Comment: Thanks to Jyrki Lahtonen, notice indeed that $\mathbb{Q}(\omega+\omega^4)=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$.

Comment: I'm glad I could be of assistance! What I often find helpful with problems like this one, is to actually draw the group structure: start out with the group $G$ at the bottom, $\{1\}$ on top and all subgroups of the same order on the same row inbetween. Then draw lines whenever one is a subgroup of another. The intermediate fields then have to follow the same structure and it's often easier to find which is which.

Comment: I will do that! Thanks. One question: Jyrki Lahtonen pointed out that I forgot some subgroups. However, when I was listing the subgroups I posted here, I didn't know if there was something to help me see if I was forgetting someone (wich I was.. ): ). Do you happen to know a way I could've verified this when I first listed them?

Comment: I have to admit that for my exam in Galois theory, I memorised all small groups and their subgroup structure, hoping Galois groups in the exam were either one of these or would be such that the subgroup structure was easy to determine. I'm afraid I can't be of much help there. In this case, one could have discovered some subgroups were missing from the fact that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\omega)$ is a so far unadressed subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha\omega,\omega+\omega^4)$.

Answer (score 2):

From $w^5=1$, after dividing with $w-1$, we get: $$w^4+w^3+w^2+w+1=0$$
As we know, $2 w^5=2$ and $w^8=w^3$, therefore previous equation is equal to:
 $$w^2+2 w^5+w^8+w+w^4-1=0,$$
which is equal to
$$(w+w^4)^2+(w+w^4)-1=0.$$
Therefore, the minimal polynomial for $w+w^4$ is $x^2+x-1$.

For other question, it is probably like this: {I, σ∘τ2} for fixed field has $Q(\alpha \omega^3, \omega^2+\omega^3)$, where the first element has order 5 and second has order 2, therefore $[Q(\alpha \omega^3, \omega^2+\omega^3):Q]=10$. It is easy to check: $w+w^4=(\omega^2+\omega^3)^2-2$, $\alpha+\alpha\omega=\alpha\omega^3(\omega^2+\omega^3)$ and $\alpha\omega^2+\alpha\omega^4=\alpha\omega^3(\omega+\omega^4)$.

Comment: So, for example, {I, $\sigma^2\circ\tau^2$} fixes $\mathbb{Q(\alpha\omega, \omega + \omega^4)}$? Because $\sigma^2\circ\tau^2(\alpha\omega)=\alpha\omega$, $[\mathbb{Q(\alpha\omega)}:\mathbb{Q}]=5$, $\sigma^2\circ\tau^2(\omega+\omega^4)=\omega+\omega^4$ and $[\mathbb{Q(\omega + \omega^4)}:\mathbb{Q}]=2$, so $[\mathbb{Q(\alpha\omega, \omega + \omega^4)}:\mathbb{Q}]=10$... Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is general rule for degrees that are primitive (gcd(2,5)=1). $[Q(αω,ω+ω4):Q]=[Q(αω,ω+ω4):Q((ω+ω4)] [Q(ω+ω4):Q]$ and $[Q(αω,ω+ω4):Q]=[Q(αω,ω+ω4):Q(αω)][Q(αω):Q]$, therefore 2 and 5 are divisors of order of group $Q(αω,ω+ω4)$ and $|Q(αω,ω+ω4)|\leq 10$, so we have $|Q(αω,ω+ω4)|=10$.