# Unique subfield $L$ of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[5]{2},\zeta_5)$ such that $[K:L]=5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

$K$ is the splitting field of the polynomial $f=x^5-2$, and we need to prove the existence of a unique subfield $L$ such that $[K:L]=5$. It would be nice to use the Galois group here, but it is a semi-direct product which I am unfamilar with. Is there a way to do this without using the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory? I know that $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=20$, so the Galois group is a group of order $20$, but I'd like to find a way to do this without invoking the fundamental theorem. Any suggestions?

Comment: The subfields are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974891/intermediate-fields-of-galx5-2-mathbbq).

Comment: I think you’re making it too hard, if you know that $\bigl[\Bbb Q(\zeta_5):\Bbb Q\bigr]=4$. That gives you a field with the desired degree beneath $K$, so all you need to do is verify that it’s unique.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice of Lubin: one can show using Sylow theory that there is a unique subgroup $P$ of $G=\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})$ with $|P|=5$. Let $L=\text{Fix}(P)$. Then by Galois Theory, we have $[K:L]=|P|=5$. The uniqueness of $L$ follows from the uniqueness of $P$. Finally, $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$ is one such extension, so $L=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)$.